# How to deduct product quantity using inventory after it is getting ordered in commercetools?

Tags: commercetools

[[image: Issue we are facing in ordering a product]]

changing inventory mode to Track only,
tax mode to Platform

Answer (score 2):

The cart must have inventoryMode set to TrackOnly or ReserveOnOrder.
You can find more details in the documentation below.

https://docs.commercetools.com/api/projects/carts#cart
https://docs.commercetools.com/api/projects/carts#inventorymode

Comment: Using the above links we have set the inventory mode to Track only in cart , even though we are facing out of stock issue. *Note: Again we are facing same issue as we shared above image.

Comment: The documentation states: 
"An Order can be created even if the Line Item quantity is zero or negative, **but if no matching Inventory Entry exists for the Line Item, an OutOfStock error is returned.**"  

Is there an existing Inventory Entry for the SKUs that you are trying to add to the cart?

https://docs.commercetools.com/api/projects/inventory#inventoryentry

Answer (score 0):

-For this inventory must be added.

-You can call inventory api and reduce the quantity which ever quantity has been ordered using line_item_id.

-It will be reflect in inventory section.

-Always check quantity on checkout page while placing an order for every product for that you can create one function which will give you product data with available quantity and you can check that with availability value.